# How do I use FileOpen (VB.NET) in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, vb.net-to-c#

So, I'm working on converting this code from VB.NET to C#:

```
    Public Class Form1
    Const filesplit As String = "|split|"
    Dim stub, opt() As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        On Error Resume Next
        FileOpen(1, Application.ExecutablePath, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared)
        stub = Space(LOF(1))
        FileGet(1, stub)
        FileClose(1)
        opt = Split(stub, filesplit)

    End Sub
End Class
```

I've used a series of online converters, and they don't really work for me.

How do I do it? I'm trying to understand VB.NET source code so I can use it in.

Comment: Are you sure that is VB.NET and not VB6?

Comment: What's `FileOpen()`?  (And `Space()`?  And `LOF()`?  And `FileGet()`?  And `FileClose()`?  And `Split()`?)  If this is VB .NET then you have some helper functions that you either need to examine and implement or move to a separate assembly and reference them as-is.  Either way, all of the file operations you would need are in the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: @David FileOpen/Space/LOF etc. are all standard functions of VB.NET (for backward compatibility with VB6; and yes, even the `On Error` statement still works in VB.NET).

Comment: This must be VB.NET code as Application.Executable path is not in VB6. Looks like it has been ported from VB6 and blindly copied and pasted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those methods are in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` Namespace.

So you could just **add a reference to that** in your project and then use virtually the exact same code with a small amount of extra qualification on the methods used:

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic; //add this statement

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        string filesplit = "|split|";
        string stub;
        string[] opt;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FileSystem.FileOpen(1, Application.ExecutablePath, OpenMode.Binary, OpenAccess.Read, OpenShare.Shared);
            stub = Strings.Space(Convert.ToInt32(FileSystem.LOF(1)));
            FileSystem.FileGet(1, ref stub);
            FileSystem.FileClose(1);
            opt = Strings.Split(stub, filesplit);
        }
    }
}
```

However you should really look into using the `File.xxx` methods in the `System.IO` namespace in both your VB.NET and C# code going forward, but this will get it working for you.

Comment: However, since this is about a translation to C#, it would be smarter to (manually) convert to C# equivalents.

Comment: @rskar - I don't disagree with you, but it would have been smarter to translate this to VB.NET code that didn't require the VisualBasic namespace in the first place.

Comment: thank you my brother and you are the best answer, thank you to any one try to help me thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [File.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b9skfh7s(v=vs.110).aspx). That should get you what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your VB code is essentially doing this:

```
// The using clause ensures the StreamReader is properly disposed after the closing block.
using (StreamReader sr = File.OpenText(Application.ExecutablePath))
{
    stub = sr.ReadToEnd();
    opt = stub.Split(filesplit).ToArray();
}
```

This assumes filesplit is a char, string or something like Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 0):

Basically you would use :

```
Dim content = File.ReadAllText("c:\temp\MyTest.txt")
```

However  it would be more correct to use:

```
Dim path As String = "c:\temp\MyTest.txt"
If File.Exists(path) Then
    Dim content = File.ReadAllText(path)
    Rem do something with content
End If
```